# Javascript: Access address bar and redirect to new URL?

Tags: javascript

I've been given an old Javascript program that keeps some state information stored in the URL, past the "#" so that the state information is not passed to the HTTP server.

```
http://example.com/oldprogram/#/some-parms
```

I need to rewrite the program, so that the parameters are handled on the server.  Additionally, I would like to redirect old URLs (saved in email, for example) to the new service.

My question:

How can I open a URL of the old form, and have Javascript rewrite the URL and redirect to the newly rewritten URL?  For discussion purposes, translating the "#" to "@" would be perfect.

i.e., clicking on this link:

```
http://example.com/oldprogram/#/some-parms
```

causes this page to be loaded:

```
http://example.com/newprogram/@/some-parms
```

Comment: `.replace("#", "@")` or am I missing something?

Comment: You can't do this on the client side.  How would you load the JavaScript in the first place if the URL you want to direct from is no longer being parsed by the server?

Comment: @LloydBanks, the data is in the address bar.  I think if the contents of the address bar can be accessed, it will include the "#..." data?

Comment: `window.location` returns the full URL.

Comment: @MarkHarrison, does the old URL show a 404 error page?

Comment: A way to solve this: on `/oldprogram/#/some-parms` load the same content as `/newprogram/@/some-parms` then use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to manipulate the address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
window.location = ("" + window.location).replace("#", "@");
```

This will redirect to the resulting URL as you've requested.
Obviously you will have to put this script into the old page.

If this is not an option there's no way you can force a redirect with JS.
There are other options like URL rewriting and redirecting through the webserver's configuration.

For Apache, as an example, you would use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).

Comment: You could just hardcode the new URL in a `<meta>` redirect.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think mod rewrite will work on URLs after the hash (#). But yea, your `replace()` code should work I reckon.

Comment: window.location is perfect, thanks.  URL rewriting doesn't work, since the browser doesn't send anything following the #.